# CLEARCASE: How do you keep tracking the upstream version

Tags: version-control, clearcase

My current employer uses clearcase (I believe Base-CC) for version control. Our project has a branch, and each user has his own branch on top of it. The configspec of the users shows elements from the user branch, then from the project branch, and then from the company-wide branch.

The current modus-operandi, is that the users merge in their changes back to the project branch, and keep working on their own branch.

The problem is, that after the user merges his changes, he still has a branch for this element. Then, when the someone else modifies the project, he still sees his outdated version.

I want the following:

- if a user has a checkedout file, display it.
- if a user has unmerged worked, display it.
- if a user has **merged work**, show the lastest version from the **project**

I thought of marking the element branch as obsolete after each merge, but the users still sees it, and not the latest from the project.

Then I thought of changing the config spec, to somehow ignore merged-in branches, but I do not know how to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse your personal `dev` branch, but the correct workflow, when a dev merges his/her branch to the upstream branch (here the `project` one) is:

- first merge the `project` branch to the personal `dev` branch
- resolve any conflict locally
- then merge personal `dev` to project.

That way:

- you don't have to modify the config spec after each merge,
- you make sure the merge will be a trivial one,
- and the personal `dev` branch can represent easily the LATEST from the upstream branch after merging (again) the project branch to the personal `dev` branch: the delta will be minimal.

Comment: Thank you!  can you please clarify the last point about representation of latest? As I understand it, after I've merged `project` to my `dev`, I'll still see my `dev` version. Then if someone else changes `project`, I will not even be aware of that fact, as I see my outdated version.

Comment: @jarondl yes, you will always see LATEST of `dev`. The point is: you can synchronize `dev` easily with LATEST of `project` on demand (with a merge from `project` to `dev`), because the delta will be minimal, meaning the merge will be very quick.

Comment: Ah I see. So instead of just merging his changes, the user should: merge `project` to `dev`, solve conflicts, merge `dev` to `project`. Then the next time something changes in project, he merges it in to `dev`, hoping it will be trivial. Thank you @VonC

Comment: Yeah, I am used to it in git, where usually you branch out, do your changes, merge in from upstream, and merge to upstream. However, in CC, branching and changing the config_spec for each change is an overkill. So users stick to their branches, and the flow is somewhat different. The weird thing to get used to is the `update` changes some files (those without local branches), but not others, and you practically have to merge after every update.